# How to use instructions for adjusting segment addresses in 8086 assembly architecture

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, x86-16

I'm trying to surmise a model I've been constructing under assembly language and I kept running into this one discrepancy I'm trying to fix. Here I have a modular file system where I am trying to build a space for a buffer file system however I have been getting stuck on the buffer address at a certain segment space. I know the 8086 standard has A0-19 data lines where A0-15 yields the size 16 segment addresses but I'm struggling whenever I need to use the other segments between A16-19 (0x0FFFF-0xFFFFF). Before I had practiced operating on the reserved VRAM areas of A0-19( 0xA0000 - 0xC0000) and here I have a simple print function to write text to these VRAM areas.
What I found is that I can indeed print from > 0x0FFFF however I can't reference any of the instructions that I have put here. As of this time this leaves 2 options at hand for me

1. My build is only able to access the memory segments passed 0x0FFFF
2. My build can only reference instructions where <= 0x0FFFF

Basically this is showing a significant design flaw in these builds in where any order that these inferences were true completely changes the model. Here distinguishes the model contrivance between 1) and 2) where 1) assigns an exclusive buffer area and 2) constricts the instructional area. What I'm afraid of is that assuming any circumstance gets me stuck so my hope was to have a review to avoid any more unnecessary convolutions.

To surmise simply what I understand is that as stated before the electronics of 8086 microprocessors are in fact standardized components such as the address component being built around these A0-15 lines. What I don't understand is how the rest of the data lines (A16-19) maps the remaining memory components. Now my main concern is that these models are still insufficient because of the substantial amount of reading to just integrate the A0-15 & A16-19 lines.

Here is a copy of a small build version from what I'm looking at

boot.asm

```
;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


[org 0x7c00]

[bits 16]

mov cx,0
mov ds,cx
mov es,cx


cld

mov si,msgString 
call kprint



mov cx,0x1000
mov es,cx
;mov bx,0x0000_9000
mov bx,0x0000_0000
;mov bx,0x0000_D000
mov cl,5
mov bx,msgString
;mov bx,0x0000_D000
mov bx,0x0000_0000
mov cl,5
mov al,1
call read_section
;mov cx,0xD00
mov cx,0x1000
mov es,cx
mov bx,0
;mov al,1
mov cl,5
mov al,1
call read_section

mov cx,0
mov ds,cx
mov es,cx

mov bx,0x0000_9200
mov cl,4
mov bx,msgString
mov bx,0x0000_9200
mov cl,4
mov al,1
call read_section
mov cx,0x920
mov es,cx
mov bx,0
;mov al,1
mov cl,4
mov al,1
call read_section


mov bx,0x0000_9000
mov cl,3
mov bx,msgString
mov bx,0x0000_9000
mov cl,3
mov al,1
call read_section
mov cx,0x900
mov es,cx
mov bx,0
;mov al,1
mov cl,3
;mov bx,0x0000_8000
mov al,1
call read_section


mov bx,0x0000_7e00
mov cl,2
mov bx,msgString
mov bx,0x0000_7e00
mov cl,2
mov al,1
call read_section
mov cx,0x7e0
mov es,cx
mov bx,0
mov cl,2
;mov bx,0x0000_8000
mov al,1
call read_section
mov bx,0x0000_7e00

;mov cx,0
;mov es,cx


pusha

jmp 0x7e00
;jmp 0x9200
;jmp 0xD000

;jmp 0x11000

;jmp 0x0000_7e0:0x0000
;jmp 0x7e0:0x0000
;jmp 0x900:0x0000
;jmp 0xfc0:0x0000


jmp $

kprint:
    cld
    mov ah,0x0E

kstring:
    lodsb
    int 0x10
    cmp al,0x00
    jnz kstring
    ret

read_section:
    
    mov ah,0x02
;   mov al,1
    mov ch,0
    mov dh,0
    int 0x13
    jc .disk_check
    ;mov si,checkString2
    ;call kprint

    ;lea si,[checkString]
    ;call printstr

    ret

.disk_check:
    ;lea si,[checkString]
    ;call printstr

    mov si,checkString
    call kprint
    jmp $
.done:
    ret


;section .data  

align 4
BOOT_DRIVE: db 0
msgString:  db 'Game platform premier',10,13,0
checkString:    db 'Section did not load',10,13,0
checkString2:   db 'disk complete',10,13,0

times 510 -($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

stage1.asm

```
;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.



;%define REBASE_ADDRESS(A)  (0x7E00 + ((A) - protectedGate1))

%define BUILD_GDT_DESC(bounds,base,access,flags) \
((( base & 0x00FFFFFF) << 16) | \
(( base & 0xFF000000) << 32) | \
( bounds & 0x0000FFFF) |        \
(( bounds & 0x000F0000) << 32) | \
(( access & 0xFF) << 40) |      \
(( flags & 0x0F) << 52))        



[ORG 0x7E00]

[BITS 16]


;section .text

protectedGate1:


;mov bx,0x0000_9000
    
    mov si,String 
    call kprint


    cld
    cli

    in al,0x92
    or al,2
    out 0x92,al

    lgdt[gdt32Ptr]
    lidt[IdtPipe]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax,1
    mov cr0, eax
    
;   jmp code32_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
    jmp code32_post:__protected_mode_32





kprint:
    cld
    mov ah,0x0E
kstring:
    lodsb
    int 0x10
    cmp al,0x00
    jnz kstring
    ret



;section .text

[bits 32]
; 32 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_32:use32
;    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ax,data32_post
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
;    mov ss, ax
    ; restate cr3
    mov cr3, ebx
    ; restate esp
    mov esp, edx

    mov cx,[gate_voucher]
    cmp word [gate_voucher],0
    jnz loopcheck
    mov word [gate_voucher],1

    jmp BIOS32_PREP
loopcheck:
    hlt
    jmp loopcheck

;   jmp 0x8000

BIOS32_PREP:use32


    pusha
    ;pushf
    ; save current esp to edx
    mov edx, esp
    ; jumping to 16 bit protected mode
    ; disable interrupts
    cli
    ; clear cr3 by saving cr3 data in ebx register
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, cr3
    mov cr3, ecx

    jmp code16_post:__protected_mode_16

[bits 16]
; 16 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_16:use16
    ; jumping to 16 bit real mode

    xor eax,eax
    xor ecx,ecx

;   mov ax, 0x38
    mov cx,data16_post

;    mov ax,0

    mov ds, cx
    mov es, cx
    mov fs, cx
    mov gs, cx
    mov ss, cx
    ; turn off protected mode
    ; set bit 0 to 0
    mov eax, cr0
    and al,  ~0x01
    mov cr0, eax

;   jmp 0x0:REBASE_ADDRESS(__real_mode_16)
    jmp 0x9000


;section .data 

String: db 'platform 2',10,13,0
checkString:    db 'check',10,13,0


gdt32:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0,0,0,0)
gdt32code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1100b)
gdt32data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1100b)
gdt16code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1000b)
gdt16data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1000b)


.stub1:

    code32_post: equ gdt32code -gdt32
    data32_post: equ gdt32data -gdt32
;.stub:
    code16_post: equ gdt16code -gdt32
    data16_post: equ gdt16data -gdt32

;   tss32_post: equ gdt32tss -gdt32
    
    gdt32Len: equ $-gdt32   
    gdt32Ptr: dw gdt32Len-1
        dd gdt32


save_cr0    dd 0
save_cr3    dd 0
saved_segment   resd 0
gate_voucher    dw 0
saved_stack resw 0




IdtPipe:
    dw 0x03ff
    dd 0





times 512-($-$$) db 0

;%include 'gdt.inc'
```

stage3.asm

```
;[org 0x9000]

[BITS 16]

;section .text
;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

%define REBASE_ADDRESS(A)  (0x9000 + ((A) - BIOS32_PREP))

%define BUILD_GDT_DESC(bounds,base,access,flags) \
((( base & 0x00FFFFFF) << 16) | \
(( base & 0xFF000000) << 32) | \
( bounds & 0x0000FFFF) |        \
(( bounds & 0x000F0000) << 32) | \
(( access & 0xFF) << 40) |      \
(( flags & 0x0F) << 52))        
;[org 0xA000]

[bits 32]
BIOS32_PREP:use32

    pusha
    ;pushf
    ; save current esp to edx
    mov edx, esp
    ; jumping to 16 bit protected mode
    ; disable interrupts
    cli
    ; clear cr3 by saving cr3 data in ebx register
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, cr3
    mov cr3, ecx


    jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)
;   jmp code16_post:__protected_mode_16


[bits 16]
; 16 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_16:use16
    ; jumping to 16 bit real mode

    xor eax,eax
    xor ecx,ecx

;   mov ax, 0x38
    mov cx,data16_post

;    mov ax,0

    mov ds, cx
    mov es, cx
    mov fs, cx
    mov gs, cx
    mov ss, cx
    ; turn off protected mode
    ; set bit 0 to 0
    mov eax, cr0
    and al,  ~0x01
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x0:REBASE_ADDRESS(__real_mode_16)


__real_mode_16:use16
    xor cx, cx
    mov ds, cx
    mov es, cx
    mov fs, cx
    mov gs, cx
    mov ss, cx
;    mov sp, 0x8c00
   mov sp, 0x6c00
 
    ; enable bios interrupts to call
    sti
    ; save current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    pusha
    mov cx, ss
    push cx
    mov cx, gs
    push cx
    mov cx, fs
    push cx
    mov cx, es
    push cx
    mov cx, ds
    push cx
    pushf
    ; get current stack pointer & save it to current_esp
    mov ax, sp
;    mov edi, current_esp
    mov di, current_esp
;    mov di, far 0001_0000:current_esp
;push ds
;   mov eax,0x00010000
;   mov ds,eax
;   mov edi, current_esp
;pop ds

    stosw
    ; load our custom registers context
    mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_in_reg16_ptr)
;    mov sp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_in_reg16_ptr)

    ; only use some general register from the given context
    popa
    ; set a new stack for bios interrupt
;    mov sp, 0x9c00
   mov sp, 0x7c00

    ; call immediate interrupt opcode to execute context

    pusha
;   mov bp,sp


;   jmp bios32_GraphicCtrlA
;   jmp 0x7e00
    jmp 0x9200
;   jmp 0x9400
;   jmp 0xD000
;   jmp 0x10000

;   mov cx,0x1000
;   mov es,cx
;   mov ds,cx
;   jmp 0:ds

;   mov ebp,0x00010000
;   push ebp
;   push 0x10000
;   retw
    
    poll_function:
    ;   mov si,page_str1
        popa
        ; get our output context here
        mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_out_reg16_ptr)
    
        add sp, 28 ; restore stack used for calling our context
        ; save current context, all general, segment registers, flags
        pushf
        mov cx, ss
        push cx
        mov cx, gs
        push cx
        mov cx, fs
        push cx
        mov cx, es
        push cx
        mov cx, ds
        push cx
        pusha
        ; restate the current_esp to continue
        mov esi, current_esp
    ;    mov si, current_esp
    
        lodsw
        mov sp, ax
        ; restore all current context, all general, segment registers, flags
        popf
        pop cx
        mov ds, cx
        pop cx
        mov es, cx
        pop cx
        mov fs, cx
        pop cx
        mov gs, cx
        pop cx
        mov ss, cx
        popa
    
    
    ;[bits 16]
    protectedGate2:use16
        cld
        cli
    
        in al,0x92
        or al,2
        out 0x92,al
    
        lgdt[gdt32Ptr]
        lidt[IdtPipe]
    
        mov eax, cr0
        or eax,1
        mov cr0, eax
    
        jmp code32_post:0x0000_7e00
;       jmp code32_post:0x0000_9200

        bios32_in_reg16_ptr:
            resw 14
        bios32_out_reg16_ptr:
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
                        dd 0xaaaaaaaa
        
        current_esp:    dw 0x0000
        

gdt32:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0,0,0,0)
gdt32code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1100b)
gdt32data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1100b)
gdt16code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1000b)
gdt16data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1000b)


.stub1:

    code32_post: equ gdt32code -gdt32
    data32_post: equ gdt32data -gdt32
;.stub:
    code16_post: equ gdt16code -gdt32
    data16_post: equ gdt16data -gdt32

;   tss32_post: equ gdt32tss -gdt32
    
    gdt32Len: equ $-gdt32   
    gdt32Ptr: dw gdt32Len-1
        dd gdt32

        IdtPipe:
            dw 0x03ff
            dd 0
        
    
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

stage4.asm

```
%define SEGMENT2 0x10000

[BITS 16]

;section .text

prep_module2:
;   jmp 0xD000
;   jmp 0xF000
;   jmp SEGMENT2:0
;   jmp 10000h


;push dword 0x00010000
;retd

;   jmp 0F000h:0
;   jmp 0x10:0x1000

vm_module:
    sub dword [vidmem_ptr],VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
;   mov si,String
    
    ;test
;   mov dx,0x3f2
;   in al,dx

    call printstr_task

loopcheck: jmp $

String: db 'Check',0

printstr_task:
    
    push cx

    mov cx,0x1000
    mov ds,cx
    mov cx,0

    mov si,0x11

    mov bp,0b800h
    mov es,bp
    mov bp,[vidmem_ptr]

prep:

    mov cx,0
    mov es,cx
    mov ax,ROWS
    mov bx,es:0x044a
    mul bx
    add ax,COLS1
;   shl ax,1
    mov bp,ax
    add bp,[vidmem_ptr]
    
;   ask the boss what that is

;check even and odd placements  
;boundary

;   mov cx,0B000H
;   test byte es:0x0410,2
;   jnz .str_address
    mov cx,0b800H
    mov es,cx
    mov ch,COLOR_ATTR_BSC

    jmp gettext


output:
;   pop word vidmem_address
    pop ax
    mov dx,ax
    mov es:[bp],dx


    add bp,byte 2

gettext:

    mov cl,byte [ds:si]
    inc si
;   mov [vidmem_address],cx
    push cx
    test cl,cl
    jnz output
    mov [vidmem_ptr],bp

    pop word [bp]
    pop ax

    mov cx,0
    mov ds,cx
    
    ret

    jmp $


;dw 0xaa55

;section .data
VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR EQU 0XB8000
COLOR_ATTR_PSC  EQU 0X6A
COLOR_ATTR_BSC  EQU 0X5F
PM_MODE_STACK   EQU 0X80000
VM_STACK_SEG    EQU 0X0000
VM_STACK_OFS    EQU 0X0000
VM_CS_SEG       EQU 0X0000
FLAGS_VM_CMP    EQU 17
FLAGS_CMP1  EQU 1
FLAGS_CMP_IF    EQU 9
RING0_PROC_STACK_SIZE   EQU 2048
;TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE        EQU 0
TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE         EQU 0x400/8
;VM_STACK_ADDRESS   EQU vidmem_address
ROWS    EQU 25
COLS1   EQU 80
BACK1   EQU 05h
FRONT1  EQU 12h
CHECKER EQU 0


align 4
vidmem_ptr: dd VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
pm_str: db 'protected mode string ',0
pm_str_length: equ $-pm_str
vm_str: db 'virtual',0
;vidmem_address: dw 0


times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

test_1.asm

```
[org 0x10000]

[BITS 16]

;section .text

prep_module2:
;   jmp 0xD000
;   jmp 0x9400

vm_module:
    sub dword [vidmem_ptr],VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
    mov si,vm_str


    call printstr_task

loopcheck: jmp $

vm_str: db 'virtual_test',0

printstr_task:
    
    push cx

    mov bp,0b800h
    mov es,bp
    mov bp,[vidmem_ptr]

prep:

    mov cx,0
    mov es,cx
    mov ax,ROWS
    mov bx,es:0x044a
    mul bx
    add ax,COLS1
;   shl ax,1
    mov bp,ax
    add bp,[vidmem_ptr]
    

;check even and odd placements
    
;   wizard tactics 1.7
    add bp,0x690
    times 20 inc bp
    ;bodary
    mov cx,0b800H
    mov es,cx
    mov ch,COLOR_ATTR_BSC

    jmp gettext


output:
;   pop word vidmem_address
    pop ax
    mov dx,ax
    mov es:[bp],dx

    add bp,byte 2

gettext:

    mov cl,byte [ds:si]
    inc si
;   mov [vidmem_address],cx
    push cx
    test cl,cl
    jnz output
    mov [vidmem_ptr],bp

    pop word [bp]
    pop ax

    mov cx,0
    mov ds,cx
    
    ret

    jmp $


;dw 0xaa55

;section .data
VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR EQU 0XB8000
COLOR_ATTR_PSC  EQU 0X6A
COLOR_ATTR_BSC  EQU 0X5F
PM_MODE_STACK   EQU 0X80000
VM_STACK_SEG    EQU 0X0000
VM_STACK_OFS    EQU 0X0000
VM_CS_SEG       EQU 0X0000
FLAGS_VM_CMP    EQU 17
FLAGS_CMP1  EQU 1
FLAGS_CMP_IF    EQU 9
RING0_PROC_STACK_SIZE   EQU 2048
;TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE        EQU 0
TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE         EQU 0x400/8
;VM_STACK_ADDRESS   EQU vidmem_address
ROWS    EQU 25
COLS1   EQU 80
BACK1   EQU 05h
FRONT1  EQU 12h
CHECKER EQU 0


align 4
vidmem_ptr: dd VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
pm_str: db 'protected mode string ',0
pm_str_length: equ $-pm_str

;vidmem_address: dw 0


times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

run.sh

```
    nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
    nasm -f bin stage1.asm -o stage1.bin

    nasm -f bin test_1.asm -o test_1.bin
    nasm -f bin page1.asm -o page1.bin

    nasm -f elf stage3.asm -o stage3_2.o
    ld -g -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x9000 stage3_2.o -o stage3_2.bin --oformat binary 

    nasm -f elf stage4.asm -o stage4_2.o
    ld -g -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x9200 stage4_2.o -o stage4_2.bin --oformat binary 



    dd if=/dev/zero of=os.bin bs=512 count=2875
    cat boot.bin    \
        stage1.bin  \
        stage3_2.bin\
        stage4_2.bin\
        test_1.bin  \
    os.bin>os.img

rm -rf *\.bin


qemu-system-i386 -hda os.img
```

As a summary I would like to acknowledge how conventional programming can be pretty overwhelming for entry level designers. This is why references and resources like this community is very essential to me here and if anyone else could share or contribute too I would really appreciate your correspondence.

Comment: It seems like you aren't really aware of 8086 segmentation. The 16-bit segment value is shifted by four, so a segment base points to a linear value between 0000h and 0F_FFF0h. Then you add the 16-bit offset to address up to 64 KiB starting from the linear segment base address. On a true 8086 or 186 this allows access to 1 MiB of address space with each paragraph (a single 16-byte chunk) addressible with 4096 different segment bases. On a 286+ nearly 1088 KiB are accessible if A20 isn't masked, as linear addresses beyond 0F_FFFFh won't wrap to the first 64 KiB any more.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with x86 segmentation, then don't.  Switch to protected mode and use a flat memory model (where every segment base is 0, limit is unlimited.)  I guess if you're writing your own bootloader that switches to protected mode, you would need to set segment registers correctly to make some of that work, though.  An EFI application will start in 64-bit mode so you never have to deal with real-mode segmentation.  (But then you have EFI calls instead of BIOS `int` calls so you'd have to rewrite some code.)  Or write code for user-space under an OS.

Comment: If you want to learn x86 segmentation, suggest to experiment with a very small program, just a few lines would suffice.  Also these articles are helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_models; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation.  That processor always generates memory references using A0-A19; it does not split the address bus into two parts (16 and 4).  It generates a full 20 bit address for each memory reference, using the formula "(segment register << 4) + offset register".  The segment register is chosen based on the offset register used, unless overridden.